# Showing a normal-derivative operator is a (sort of) contraction (related to Crandall-Liggett and PDEs)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Denote by $\mathbb{E}(g)$ the solution of the PDE
$$\Delta v(x,y) = 0 \quad\text{in $\Omega$}$$
$$v(x,0) = g(x) \quad\text{on $\partial\Omega$}.$$
Let $X=L^1(\partial\Omega)$. Let $h(t)$ be a differentiable function and define $A(t)\colon D(A) \subset X  \to X$ by
$$ A(t;v) = -\text{trace}\left(\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}(v^m)}{\partial y}\right)h(t),$$
$$D(A(t)) = D(A)= \{v \in L^\infty(\partial\Omega) \mid A(v) \in L^1(\partial\Omega), |{v}|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)} \leq |{f}|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}\}.$$

It follows that $A(t)$ is accretive, that is, that $J_\lambda(A(t)) := (I+\lambda A(t))^{-1}$ is a contraction: 
$$|{J_{\lambda}(A) g_1-J_{\lambda}(A) g_2}|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)} \leq |{ g_1 -  g_2}|_{L^1(\partial\Omega)}.$$

> **I want to show that** there exists a continuous $F\colon [0,T] \to X$ and a monotone increasing function $L\colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such that
>   $$ |{J_\lambda(A(t)) g - J_\lambda(A(s)) g}|_{X} \leq \lambda |{F(t) - F(s)}|_{X}L(|{ g}|_{X})\tag{1}$$
>   for $0 < \lambda$, $ \leq t, s \leq T$ and $ g \in \overline{D(A)}$.

The following is my attempt:

---

Let $u_t = J_{\lambda}(A(t)) g$ and $u_s$ similarly. So with $w=u^m$, 
$$\Delta_\Omega  w_t = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial  w_t}{\partial y} = \frac{ u_t - g}{\lambda h(t)}
$$
and the weak formulation is
$$\int_{\Omega}\nabla_\Omega  w_t \nabla_\Omega  \varphi = \int_{\partial\Omega}\varphi\left(\frac{ g- u_t }{\lambda h(t)}\right)$$
and subtracting one from the other:
$$
\lambda\int_{\Omega}\nabla_\Omega ( w_t-  w_s) \nabla_\Omega  \varphi 
= \int_{\partial\Omega}\varphi\left(\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right)( g- u_s) - \varphi\left(\frac{ u_t- u_s}{h(t)}\right).
$$
Now I pick $ \varphi = p_\delta( w_t -  w_s)$ where $p_\delta$ is a monotone approximation of the sign function. Then we find
$$
\lambda\int_{\Omega}p_\delta'( w_t -  w_s)|\nabla_\Omega ( w_t-  w_s)|^2 + \int_{\partial\Omega}p_{\delta}( w_t -  w_s)\left(\frac{ u_t- u_s}{h(t)}\right)
= \int_{\partial\Omega}p_{\delta}( w_t -  w_s)\left(\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right)( g -  u_s)$$
Throwing away the first term on the left (safe to assume it is positive) and passing to the limit:
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}\text{sign}( w_t -  w_s)\left(\frac{ u_t- u_s}{h(t)}\right)
= \int_{\partial\Omega}\text{sign}( w_t -  w_s)\left(\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right)( g -  u_s)\\
\leq \left|\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right|\int_{\partial\Omega}| g| + \left|\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right|\int_{\partial\Omega}| u_s|
$$
Now note that $J_{\lambda}(A(s))0 = 0$, so $|{ u_s}|{} = |{J_{\lambda}(A(s)) g - J_{\lambda}(A(s))0}|{} \leq |{ g}|{}$ by contractivity. So the above becomes
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}| u_t- u_s|
\leq 2h(t)\left|\frac{1}{h(t)}-\frac{1}{h(s)}\right||{g}|_{X}
$$

---

This is as close as I get. I can probably bound the $h(t)$ from above so forget about that. **The issue is that it obviously does not satisfy the desired (1). How do I get the $\lambda$ in there?!**

Edit: The reason I need this condition is to obtain existence of PDE with the time-dependent operator $A(t)$ I defined above. This condition is from the paper by Crandall and Pazy I think. Maybe there is a different work that gives the same result with an easier condition to check on the time dependence?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your notations: 


 $y$ is the normal to the boundary? 


What is $f$ in the definition of $D(A)$ : as it does not appear in the problem, do you mean $|v|_{L^\infty(\partial\Omega)}\leq M$, is it that $g=f$?

In your attempt, line 1, what is $u^m$?

Comment: Yes, $y$ is normal. Sorry, yes, as you wrote, just take $|f|$ in the definition to be some given constant. As for $u^m$, that should be $u_t^m$ (and/or $u_s^m$). I missed out the subscript to avoid repetition.